# Mock Service class that has Autowired dependencies

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, mockito, junit4

I have a Service class & a config class as below:

```
public class MyService{

 @Autowired
 MyConfig myconfig;

 @Autowired
 private WebClient webClient;

 private String result;

 public String fetchResult(){
   return webClient.get().uri(myConfig.getUrl()).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
 }
}

@ConfigurationProperties("prefix="somefield")
@Component
class MyConfig{
   private String url;
   //getter & setter
  }
}
```

**Below is the Junit:**

```
@Runwith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestMe{

    @InjectMocks
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void myTest(){
       when(myService.fetchResult().then return("dummy");
    }
}
```

I am getting null pointer error when I run this class at webClient in Service class.
What could be the issue. I am new to JUnits.
How do I write a proper JUnit for this.

Comment: The test you presented makes little sense. You only stubbed one method on object under test. You got NPE, and rightfully so - you called a method on object under test with uninitialised members. NPE covered another problem: you are trying to stub methods on an object that is not a mock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make the class testable is to use constructor injection

```
public class MyService{
  private final MyConfig myconfig;
  private final WebClient webClient;
  private String result;

  @AutoWired
  MyService(
    MyConfig myconfig,
    WebClient webClient
  ) {
    this.myconfig = myconfig;
    this.webClient = webClient;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: This works for me. One doubt, if I have stepExecution in MyService class, how do I call it from Junit? it is giving NPE.

Comment: Just by `myService.stepExecution`. I looked at your question and your test treats the myService like a mock. You should be clear which things you want to mock and which things you want to test.

Comment: I have changed my test case & now I am using autowiring via constructor. but now stuck in NPE on stepexecution of spring batch that is used in service class.

Comment: Did you read https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk_bkp/reference/html/testing.html already?

Comment: Yeah, I read it few mins back & got it solved with MetaDataInstanceFactory as suggested in the docs. Many thanks for your effort and time.